# Trouble Getting re.sub to Match Newline and Any Character

Tags: python, regex

How do I get `re.sub` to match both newlines and any character.

Fox example, I tried

```
 re.sub('(?<================ K# 1 ===============)([.*\n]?)(?===================================================)', 'test', bc)
```

only to get

```
    '=============== K # 1 ===============test\nme\nhere==================================================\n'
```

where `bc` is

```
    '=============== K # 1 ===============test\nme\nhere==================================================\n'
```

when I really want to replace the entire string of `test\nme\nhere` with just `test`.

Hoping for

```
'=============== K # 1 ===============test==================================================\n'
```

Am I understanding something wrong conceptually. I have also tried `re.DOTALL` but I believe `re.sub` doesn't take flags.

Comment: Your example works the same with fewer equal signs. It just makes it hard for us (and you) having all those equal signs.

Comment: `re.sub` does take flags. `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`

Answer (score 2):

> I have also tried `re.DOTALL` but I believe `re.sub` doesn't take flags.

You believe wrong :)

```
bc = '== K# 1 ==test\nme\nhere==='
print re.sub('(?<== K# 1 ==)(.*?)(?==)', 'test', bc, 0, re.DOTALL)
# == K# 1 ==test===

# OR
print re.sub('(?<== K# 1 ==)(.*?)(?==)', 'test', bc, flags=re.DOTALL)
# == K# 1 ==test===
```

Also note that you have a space in `bc` (`"K #"`) but no space in the pattern (`"K#"`).